# How to use Zend Framework 2 with MS SQL Server on *nix?

Tags: sql-server, zend-framework2, zend-db

What, if it exists, is the canonical way to use ZF2 with MS SQL Server on a non-Windows OS?

From what I can tell from the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html), only the Sqlsrv driver is officially supported, which only works on the Windows platform.

In ZF1, we used the `Pdo_Mssql` adapter and specified the `pdoType` as `dblib`. I can't find any references to doing anything similar in ZF2.

Apparently there **was** a Pdo\Mssql driver some time ago which was removed during a major [refactoring](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/commit/00a12ad252fd83fbec486ab6f761d4d820b0a36b), but I don't see a currently documented way of using Pdo_Dblib.

According to the adapter documentation above, you can set the driver in the adapter config to `Pdo=OtherPdoDriver`, but there's no documented examples of this usage. Does that mean you can use `Pdo=Pdo_Dblib` or `Pdo=dblib` and it will work automagically?

I've found passing references to a PDO ODBC driver, which would be a usable alternative, but can't find any documentation or code references.

Comment: There's `Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Sqlsrv`, sqlsrv is a php extension (by microsoft), I don't have anything to test with, but combining the two should provide a solution. Php sqlsrv man page -> http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php github zf2 driver code -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Sqlsrv/Sqlsrv.php

Comment: Crisp, as I noted in my question, and as nofreeusername points out in his proffered answer, Sqlsrv only works on the Windows platform. FYI, if you're suggesting an Answer, do so instead of commenting. That way if it works, I can accept your Answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my obvious misunderstanding of the sqlsrv php extension, I had the mistaken idea it was a drop-in replacement for the seemingly defunct mssql one, didn't realise it was platform dependent :-/ As for not posting as an answer I wouldn't provide an answer unless I was reasonably sure it worked but unfortunately as I said, I've no way of testing, which is why I chose only to leave a comment hinting at a possible (or not) solution.

Answer (score 3):

Install the php5-sybase.  Make sure that `freetds` is installed.  You should have a conf file under `/etc/freetds` called `freetds.conf`.

In your `freetds.conf` file you should setup your mssql connection like this:

```
[MyMsSqlServer]
host = symachine.domain.com
port = 5000
tds version = 5.0
```

Then, (using the ZF2 Albums Tutorial as an example here) you set up the adapter like this:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'dblib:host=MyMsSqlServer;dbname=zf2tutorial',
        'charset'        =>  'UTF-8',
        'username'       => 'username',
        'password'       => 'password',
        'pdotype'       => 'dblib',
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

See if this gets you anywhere and let me know.  I had a bitch of a time getting this to work, and I am more then happy to help anyone else that is having issues with this!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pdo connection with pdotype set to dblib (with loaded pdo_dblib extension).
**sqlsrv is only available for Windows.**

Here you can see how freetds and unixodbc is configured to connect to a MS SQL Server.
http://featurebug.blogspot.de/2011/01/mac-os-x-php-zend-server-ce-freetds-and.html

**UPDATE:**
Here is an example how to use a connection string to connect:

```
$db = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(
    array(
        'driver'        => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'dblib:host=mssql_freetds;',
        'username'       => 'mssql_username',
        'password'       => 'mssql_password',
        )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempted answer, but did you actually read my question? I specifically acknowledged that Sqlsrv "only works on the Windows platform". Furthermore, I referred to successfully using Pdo_Mssql and with a pdoType of dblib in ZF1. You didn't offer anything new as it relates to using ZF2.

Comment: If you were referring to Crisp's comment (which should have been an Answer), it should have been in a follow-up comment, not a suggested Answer to my original question.

Comment: Yes, read your question. With ZF2 Db Adapter you can use any PDO driver, so you should use a PDO connection. To have a connection to MS SQL server, you need the pro_dblib driver and you have to set the pdoType to dblib, furthermore you need freetds and unixodbc on the server side, too. There is also a ZF2 module for that. Please take a look, but i haven'T tested this module yet: https://github.com/mabuzagu/PDODblibModule

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use odbc to connect. It is not currently officially supported, but you can get it working fairly easily, with minimal modifications.

The first thing you need to do, is make sure you can connect using the basic PHP PDO functions. So, do something like this:

```
$resource = new PDO('odbc:driver=FreeTDS;dbname=MYDB;Server=127.0.0.1;Port=8090;UID=Testuser;PWD=testpass;', 'Testuser', 'testpass', array());
$s = $resource->prepare('SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE');
$r=$s->execute();
var_dump($r);
```

You'll need to change the host, port, user, pass, table name etc. for your settings, but you can use this to make sure you have those details right. Once you know what you are doing to connect, you can access it with Zend, like this:

```
$configArray = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_odbc',
    'driver_options' => array('driver' => 'FreeTDS'),
    'platform' => 'Mssql',
    'dbname' => 'MYDB',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => 8090,
    'user' => 'Testuser',
    'pass' => 'testpass'
);

$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configArray);

$q = new Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$q->from('TEST_TABLE');
$sql = $q->getSqlString($adapter->platform);
$r = $adapter->query($sql);
echo $r->getSql()."\n";
$result = $r->execute();
while(($res = $result->next()) !== false){
    print_r($res);
}
```

**However** this will not actually work, for two reasons. First, the platform - Zend currently doesn't have an mssql platform; it defaults to sql92, which *will not work*, because it quotes identifiers in `""`, when mssql needs them to be quoted with `[]`. So you'll need to copy the Zend/Db/Adapter/Platform/Sql92.php as Mssql.php, and change it to use `[` and `]` instead of `"`.

Second, because the dsn for connection to odbc requires the driver field, which zend currently doesn't support. You'll need to open up the Driver/Pdo/Connection class and modify the connect function, to add `$dsn[] = "driver={$options['driver']}";` and replace `$dsn[] = "host={$hostname}";` with `$dsn[] = "server={$hostname}";` when $pdoDriver = odbc.

Note that the other answers are posted by people who do not actually understand how the Zend 2 library works - if you specify a value for 'dsn', then the other fields are **ignored**. I have NO idea where they got the idea of 'pdotype', as that is not a field that appears anywhere in the code.