# OFFSET and FETCH NEXT aka LIMIT for SQL Server in Zend Framework 2

Tags: sql-server, zend-framework2, limit, offset

How can I create OFFSET and FETCH NEXT in Zf2 logic? The result should be like the following

```
    SELECT * FROM mytable
  ORDER BY id DESC
    OFFSET 100 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9241984/578648).
When using the following code

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$select->order('id DESC');
$select->offset(100);
$select->limit(10);
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```

then the output is

```
SELECT [mytable].* 
FROM  [mytable] 
ORDER BY [id] DESC 
LIMIT '10' OFFSET '100'
```

which does not work for SQL Server. The output I need is the one from above.

The config in db.config.php looks like the following

```
'db_sql_server' => array(
        'driver'    => 'pdo',
        'dsn'       => 'dblib:host=myhost;dbname=mydatabase',
        'username'  => 'myusername',
        'password'  => 'mypasswort',
),
```

I skiped the 'db' config for mysql here.
And in global.php

```
return array(
  'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        /**
         * Adapter SQL Server
         */
        'Application\Db\AdapterSQLServer' => function($sm) {
            $config = $sm->get('Config');
            return new Adapter($config['db_sql_server']);
        },
    ),
  ),
)
```

to which I refere in Module.php with Table Gateway.

Comment: Did you install it correctly? [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19596234/3893182) | [samsonasik](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/zend-framework-2-working-with-sql-server/)

Comment: Yes, the connection to the SQL Server works. Other statements can be executed. The problem is just that ZF2 translates "offset" and "limit" to the eg MySQL statement and not to the SQL server statement as described above.

Comment: Could you provide Config and your whole Query from `select` till some kind of `getResult`

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: Which instance is your adapter? `get_class($tableGateway->getAdapter())`

Comment: This yields `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`

Comment: I found another way to get the adapter by using `$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->platform` where I receive `Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\SqlServer`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the driver name in the 'db_sql_server' config array from

```
'driver' => 'pdo'
```

to

```
'driver' => 'sqlsrv'
```

Comment: 'sqlsrv'  only works on Windows with DLLs but I am using a Linux system with FreeTDS.

Comment: well, you will have to implement an own FreeTds adapter then ... or maybe try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15594853/1558846